# template * is not defined () - Bolt CMS

Tags: php, twig, silex, bolt-cms

I'm moving one of my Bolt 1.6 sites to 2.0 but I'm running into the following problem when trying to render a twig template for an email:

Code:

```
return $app['twig']->render($app['config']->get('general/template/email'));
```

Response:

```
Class: Twig_Error_Loader
Message: Template "twig/template/enquiry-email.twig" is not defined ().
Code: 0
```

The following code also produces the same result:

```
return $app['render']->render($template);
```

The template is defined in app/config.yml under the key template/email

I can confirm that the template definitely exists and was previously working in version 1.6. I've also tried it with other templates which work in other functions within the same class but it still produces the same result.

It also renders the template if I don't POST any parameters.

The code is being executed within my own controller (appController.php). Which renders other views without issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just a wild guess, did you run ```composer update``` to update dependencies?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did run composer update. I also started from a fresh Bolt 2.0 repo and copied my changes in rather than overwriting existing files.

Comment: Mmm, maybe it's time to open an [issue](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in Bolt 2.1.0 - [Github issue](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/issues/2874)